# Serial Port Connection to OBD II Adapter

Tags: c++, c++11, serial-port, obd-ii, elm327

I am trying to communicate with an OBD II adapter with ELM327 chip for the first time (similar to [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C13M3W78) but without the HS CAN switch). I am using a Macbook running on Catalina (10.15.7), and when I connect the OBD II adapter to the laptop (not to the car), I'm able to see a directory for the adapter (located in /dev/cu.usbmodemxxxxx). I've written a script in C++ to try to send some AT commands and see the responses (general ones like "ATZ\r" or "ATI\r") but I always see response set at zero.

**Update 2**
I tried to perform the same procedure on a Windows laptop, so had to change APIs resulting in the following code snippet:
//Header files
#include <windows.h>

```
std::string readFromSerialPort(HANDLE serialHandle)
{
    const int bufferSize = 256;
    char buffer[bufferSize] = {};
    DWORD bytesRead = 0;

    if (!ReadFile(serialHandle, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, &bytesRead, NULL))
    {
        std::cerr << "Error reading from serial port" << std::endl;
    }
    
    buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';
    return std::string(buffer);
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE serialHandle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\COMx", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (serialHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open serial port" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    if (!GetCommState(serialHandle, &dcbSerialParams))
    {
        std::cerr << "Error getting serial port state" << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(serialHandle);
        return 1;
    }
    dcbSerialParams.fBinary = TRUE;
    dcbSerialParams.fParity = FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;
    dcbSerialParams.fDsrSensitivity = FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.fTXContinueOnXoff = TRUE;
    dcbSerialParams.fOutX = FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.fInX = FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.fErrorChar = FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.fNull = FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_ENABLE;
    dcbSerialParams.fAbortOnError = FALSE;

    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_38400;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;

    if (!SetCommState(serialHandle, &dcbSerialParams)) 
    {
        std::cerr << "Error setting serial port state" << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(serialHandle);
        return 1;
    }

    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 0 };
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = MAXDWORD;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;

    if (!SetCommTimeouts(serialHandle, &timeouts)) 
    {
        std::cerr << "Error setting serial port timeouts" << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(serialHandle);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!PurgeComm(serialHandle, PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXCLEAR)) {
        std::cerr << "Error flushing serial port buffers" << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(serialHandle);
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> atz_commands = {"ATZ\r", "ATI\r"};
    DWORD bytesWritten = 0;
    std::string response = "";
    std::string atz_command = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < atz_commands.size(); i++) 
    {
        bytesWritten = 0;
        atz_command = atz_commands[i];

        if (!WriteFile(serialHandle, atz_command.c_str(), atz_command.length(), &bytesWritten, NULL))
        {
            std::cerr << "Error writing to serial port" << std::endl;
            CloseHandle(serialHandle);
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Successfully wrote to serial port" << std::endl;
            Sleep(2000);
            response = readFromSerialPort(serialHandle);
            std::cout << response << std::endl;
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(serialHandle);
    return 0;
}
```

This seems to work, I'm able to see outputs on the terminal (OK, ELM v1.5, etc.). So not sure if it's something to do with platform dependency.

**Update**
I've used a terminal emulation program (Minicom, Screen) to try to communicate (eg. `minicom -D /dev/cu.usbmodemxxxx` and `minicom -D /dev/tty.usbmodemxxxx`. I'm able to go in but the screen is empty (whenever I type keys, nothing shows up on the screen). I do see the lights flash whenever I type anything, but the terminal shows nothing.

I've modified the C++ file to the following to add return codes and set parity bit, stop, and data, but still encounter the same issue:

```
int main() {
    const char *device_path = "/dev/cu.usbmodemxxxxx";
    
    struct termios options;
    int serial_port;
    
    serial_port = open(device_path, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    
    if (serial_port == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening serial port" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        fcntl(serial_port, F_SETFL, 0);

        if (tcgetattr(serial_port, &options) == -1) {
            perror("Error getting terminal attributes");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Successfully executed tcgetattr." << std::endl;
        }

        options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD); 
        options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
        options.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);

        options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;                     // Bitwise AND operator. No parity
        options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;                     // 1 stop bit
        options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;                      // Clears the data size bits (CSIZE) to ensure a clean slate
        options.c_cflag |= CS8;                         // 8 data bits (This specifies eight bits per byte.)

        options.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
        options.c_cc[VTIME] = 100;
        
        cfsetispeed(&options, B9600); // Tried with both B9600 and B38400.
        cfsetospeed(&options, B9600); // Tried with both B9600 and B38400.
        
        if (tcsetattr(serial_port, TCSANOW, &options) == -1)
        {
            perror("Error setting terminal attributes");
            return 1;
        }

        if (tcflush(serial_port, TCIOFLUSH) == -1)
        {
            perror("Error flushing terminal");
            return 1;
        }
        
        std::string atz_command = "ATI\r"; // I've also tried "ATZ\r", "ATI\n", "ATZ\n"
        ssize_t bytesWritten = write(serial_port, atz_command.c_str(), atz_command.length());
        if (bytesWritten == -1)
        {
            perror("Error writing to serial port.");
            return 1;
        }

        char buffer[64];
        ssize_t bytesRead = read(serial_port, buffer, 64);
        if (bytesRead == -1)
        {
            perror("Error reading from serial port.");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Buffer message: " << buffer << std::endl;
        }
    }

    close(serial_port);
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I received:

```
Successfully opened serial port.
Successfully executed tcgetattr.
Successfully executed tcsetattr.
Successfully executed tcflush.
Successfully wrote to serial port: 4 bytes.
Successfully read from serial port: 0 bytes.
Buffer message:
```

Comment: For starters, you should use ~ not ! to mask the flags.  You haven't set the Parity, Stop or Data bits.  Are you getting an immediate response (ie. non-blocking) or is it waiting the 100 Deciseconds (10secs)?  Try a \n not \r at the end. You may have to sleep between the write and read, or hang around and poll for a while until the modem has a chance to respond.

Comment: Thanks, so I've changed how I masked the flags and set the Parity, Stop and Data bits with (&= ~PARENB, &= ~CSTOPB, &= ~CSIZE, |= CS8). I tried changing to '\n' but still it doesn't show. I've also added a sleep before invoking read() for about 30 seconds. I used this condition to check whether the response was instantaneous or timeout: if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) { // Timeout } else { // Instantaneous } and seems to indicate that the response was immediate.

Comment: "*so I've changed how ...*" - Then update your post so we don't have to guess what you've done. "*I've also added a sleep ...*" - That's misguided. Your program is not synchronized with I/O. Change VMIN and VTIME instead, and let the kernel deal with it at a lower level. "*response was instantaneous or timeout*" - You're confusing the 'return' with a "*response*". A response would be data from the far-end device. Also **errno** only has meaning when the return code is `-1`. Therefore "*response was immediate*" is a bogus conclusion.

Comment: You also need to check the return code from each/every syscall, especially because your program is not producing the results you expect. Without this simple debugging step, you could be wondering a long time why your code isn't producing results while the error information was available.

Comment: At this point, I would perform a sanity check, by replacing your code with a terminal emulation program, e.g. **minicom**, to confirm that this device can actually communicate with the host.

Comment: Next thing I would try is to put a NULL Modem inline (or swap RX/TX) to check the wiring.  You should also add a loop around the read (with some delay/yield).  Then after that replace the Modem with Putty on a laptop/PC so you can control what is being sent.

Comment: "*I've used a terminal emulation program ... but the terminal shows nothing*" - Be sure to go through the various setup menus, e.g. verify the terminal & serial line settings. Your device probably is not *echoing* what you send to it, so to see what you type, you can enable `local echo`. This may turn into a hardware connection issue. What is the connection? USB? RS-232 or just UART TTL?

Comment: I've enabled local echo on minicom and can see the commands I typed. However, it's still not able to read any responses from the OBD II adapter. This works on my Windows laptop though (I can query PIDs with it), so I don't know if my OBD II adapter is somehow specific to Windows. I've also installed FTDI and VCP drivers as well updated the OS to Monterey on my Mac, but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure whether this is your problem, but with regards to serial communication, macOS exhibits ugly behavior in that a) it resets the configured bitrate once the file descriptor gets closed and b) it often takes multiple approaches to successfully configure the bitrate.

Here's example code that might be helpful:
https://github.com/Cornucopia-Swift/CornucopiaStreams/blob/fbed1496f484b3db52595d9371ed4b86b6a21c7c/Sources/CornucopiaStreams/Streams/TTYInputStreamProxy.swift#L30